# Using FB Messenger To share link

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

I am trying to share a link using the FB messenger.  When i try to share the link to facebook i keep getting an error.  I googled for an answer and the couple of solutions i found did not help since everything in the plist is correct. If anyone has any advice i would really appreciate it, been trying to solve this all day.

Error:

```
Invalid use of FBAppCall, fb839771929379526 is not registered as a URL Scheme. Did you set 'FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix' in your plist?
```

Code:

```
    // Check if the Facebook app is installed and we can present
    // the message dialog
    FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] init];
    params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    params.name = @"My Video";


    // If the Facebook app is installed and we can present the share dialog
    if ([FBDialogs canPresentMessageDialogWithParams:params]) {
        // Enable button or other UI to initiate launch of the Message Dialog
        // Present message dialog
        [FBDialogs presentMessageDialogWithLink:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://developers.facebook.com/ios"] handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {

            if(error) {
            // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
            // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
            NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error messaging link: %@", error.description
            ]);
            } else {
            // Success
            NSLog(@"result %@", results);
            }
        }];
    }  else {
        // Disable button or other UI for Message Dialog
    }

}
```

Comment: Show your custom URL configuration plz

Comment: are talking about the plist?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/troubleshooting Step 2: Set up your callback URL

Add a FacebookUrlSchemeSuffix key to your .plist file and assign it your suffix as value. In this case foo:

Comment: i added it to my plist and still get the same error

Comment: nevermind got it too work. there was something wrong with my plist url schemes.  Thanks for your help @GrzegorzKrukowski

Comment: Before the sharing code runs write this line 
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"fb-messenger://share"]];